# RSpec compare Job enqueued for a later time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-activejob

I have a job called `DisableInvitationJob`. I call it like this:

```
DisableInvitationJob.set(wait: 7.days).perform_later(invitation: @invitation)
```

And when testing the call with RSpec:

```
it {
expect(DisableInvitationJob).to have_been_enqueued
.with(invitation: Invitation.last)
.on_queue("default")
.at(7.days.from_now.change(:usec => 0))
.exactly(:once)
}
```

It fails like this:

```
expected to enqueue exactly 1 jobs, with [{:invitation=>#<Invitation id: 16, email: "test@test.io", expiration_date: "2023-03-11", oauth_token: "Yxw6qi2mqpDaBztnjRTaQEvXJnb5ot9G3FmX", group_id: 10, sender_id: 41, recipient_id: nil, created_at: "2023-03-04 20:10:07.345964000 +0900", updated_at: "2023-03-04 20:10:07.346646000 +0900", disabled: false>}], on queue default, at 2023-03-11 20:10:07 +0900, but enqueued 0
       Queued jobs:
         DisableInvitationJob job with [{:invitation=>#<Invitation id: 16, email: "test@test.io", expiration_date: "2023-03-11", oauth_token: "Yxw6qi2mqpDaBztnjRTaQEvXJnb5ot9G3FmX", group_id: 10, sender_id: 41, recipient_id: nil, created_at: "2023-03-04 20:10:07.345964000 +0900", updated_at: "2023-03-04 20:10:07.346646000 +0900", disabled: false>}], on queue default, at 2023-03-11 20:10:07 +0900
```

What is failing is the `at` part of the test. Even though the queue dates are the same by the second.

If I remove it:

```
it {
expect(DisableInvitationJob).to have_been_enqueued
.with(invitation: Invitation.last)
.on_queue("default")
.exactly(:once)
}
```

It works. How can I test it with the `at` part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used `wait_until` referencing the [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec%2FRails%2FMatchers:have_been_enqueued)

This is how I call the job

```
 DisableInvitationJob.set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon + 7.days).perform_later(invitation: invitation)
```

This is how I test it:

```
it "enqueues a job to disable the invitation" do
 expect(DisableInvitationJob).to have_been_enqueued
 .with(invitation: Invitation.last)
 .on_queue("default")
 .at(Date.tomorrow.noon + 7.days)
 .exactly(:once)
end
```